# sklearn.svm.SVC doesn't give the index of support vectors for sparse dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, libsvm, scikit-learn, scikits

sklearn.svm.SVC doesn't give the index of support vectors for sparse dataset. Is there any hack/way to get the index of SVs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without going to the cython code I am afraid. This has been on the todo list for way to long. Any help with it would be much appreciated. It shouldn't be too hard, I think.